Automatic updates without a Gateway with MongoDB connector
I'm trying to schedule automatic updates without a Gateway in Power BI for a report that uses a MongoDB connector. I've been doing some research and from what I've seen, it's not possible with this connector, only with the Gateway. Does anyone know any tricks to automatically update a report with this connector without using a Gateway?
I searched the internet and the official MongoDB forum says it requires the Gateway.
Currently, I can't work with a DW and can't use Direct Query. I specifically need to use this connector.
